# Proxy settings not working with Chrome Webview

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, proxy

Proxy settings not working with chrome webview. Is it possible to force android to use android system webview in android 7.0 and up programatically?

Comment: This problem has been introduced by recent Google Chrome update (June 1).

Comment: Issue reported here : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=851995

Answer (score 0):

With Chrome67 on Android, still proxy setting codes works, but with limitations.
Try to set proxyinfo before webview instantiated.
Maybe dynamic proxy change also still works but with limited threads.(not UI thread)
I had same problem and still analyzing how proxy setting code can work...

Comment: could you probably explain what you mean by `dynamic proxy change also still works but with limited threads.(not UI thread)`? Should I set proxy in background thread?